# MySQL: If Then Query Statement Based On If Groupings Have Less Than a Particular Number

Tags: mysql

I have a table with name, organizer, score1, and score2. The initial part that works is an extremely simple query.

Query 1:

```
 SELECT * FROM mvan m
 WHERE m.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 AND m.score2 > 60;
```

That's basically all I need and it works great. But the thing is that I need a bare minimum of 25 rows to return for each organizer -- and that query doesn't get me 25 for each. I could change the query to the following, but the problem is that then it wouldn't be optimized (since obviously the NULL values in score1 are less desirable than the ones that aren't NULL).

Query 2:

```
 SELECT * FROM mvan m
 WHERE (m.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 OR m.score1 IS NULL) AND m.score2 > 60;
```

Is there any way to write the code that it would use the first query if the count of rows per organizer were >= 25 and use the second query if it was < 25?

--

EDIT:

Here's the closest I got, but it uses a UNION ALL which I don't want because that just lumps both queries on top of each other. But I think this gives a general depiction of what I want:

```
SELECT *
FROM mvan m
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT organizer, count(*) As namecount
    FROM mvan m
    WHERE (m.score1 between 30 and 80 OR m.score1 IS NULL) AND m.score2 > 60)
    GROUP BY organizer) t1
ON m.organizer = t1.organizer
WHERE t1.namecount < 25
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM mvan m
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT organizer, count(*) As namecount
    FROM mvan m
    WHERE  (m.score1 between 30 and 80) AND m.score2 > 60)
    GROUP BY organizer) t2
ON m.organizer = t2.organizer
WHERE t2.namecount >= 25;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP MySQLi (it's probably better):

```
$connection = ...; #mysqli stuff
$query1 = ...;
$query2 = ...;
$result = $connection->query($query1);
if ($result->num_rows < 25) {
  $result = $connection->query($query2);
}//if
```

Pure SQL (this is inefficient; you should use PHP or something). I had to manually specify column names; you could use `*` in place of `col1, col2, col3` but you end up with a "count" column cluttering the results if you do:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as count FROM (<query 1>) q11) a1 
  CROSS JOIN 
    (<query 1>) a2 
  WHERE a1.count >= 25
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as count FROM (<query 1>) q12) a3 
  CROSS JOIN 
    (<query 2>) a4 
  WHERE a3.count < 25;
```

Or, written with your queries included:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as count FROM (SELECT * FROM mvan m
       WHERE t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 AND m.score2 > 60;) q11) a1 
  CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM mvan m
       WHERE t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 AND m.score2 > 60;) a2 
  WHERE a1.count >= 25
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM 
    (SELECT count(*) as count FROM (<SELECT * FROM mvan m
       WHERE t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 AND m.score2 > 60;) q12) a3 
  CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM mvan m
       WHERE (t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 OR t.score1 IS NULL) AND m.score2 > 60;) a4 
  WHERE a3.count < 25;
```

I'll also point out that it looks like your initial queries are invalid; what table has the alias t?

Comment: Thanks for trying/helping! I'll check back.

Comment: @Ryan is there a reason it needs to be pure SQL?

Comment: Thanks! This looks really close. Also, I mistyped `t` -- they should all be `m`. When I clean up the query a bit, the count column has the same number repeating. I think it has something to do potentially with `count(*)` -- it seems like it might need to be some count function where it groups organizer together. So if "Ryan" repeats in the organizer column more than 25 times, then use query 1 but if it doesn't, use query 2.

Comment: And the only reason why I'm using pure SQL is because that's all I know. Definitely open to learning PHP MySQL, but I just don't know it right now. I'm on a Mac using SequelPro to do most of my stuff.

Comment: Is there a way to make something like this the count? I figured this out to put the count of how many rows are attached to each organizer name -- but I can't figure out how to insert it into your query: `SELECT m.organizer, t.namecount
FROM mvan m
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT organizer, count(*) As namecount
    FROM mvan m
    GROUP BY organizer) t
ON m.organizer = t.organizer;`

Comment: @Ryan the repeating count column is hard to avoid - as I said, you have to manually specify the columns to select to avoid including it (as far as I know). This is pretty hacky - everything about doing this screams "just use PHP". MySQL isn't really meant to do this kind of logic.

Comment: @Ryan I think I could figure out this other query if I knew what your table schema was; I was doing my work yesterday with a table called "lol" and it got confusing translating in my head

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90943/discussion-between-devin-howard-and-ryan).

Answer (score 0):

If you need 25 rows, then use `order by` with `limit`.  Just prioritize the rows that you want:

```
SELECT *
FROM mvan m
ORDER BY (t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80) DESC,
         (m.score2 > 60) DESC
LIMIT 25;
```

This prioritizes the rows you want and takes the rest.

EDIT:

```
SELECT *
FROM mvan m
WHERE (t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 AND t.score1 IS NULL) AND 
      (m.score2 > 60)
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN t.score1 BETWEEN 30 and 80 AND m.score2 > 60
               THEN 1
               WHEN t.score1 IS NULL ans m.score2 > 60 
               THEN 2
          END)
LIMIT 25;
```

I missed the nuance of your question.  You want rows where `score1` is `NULL`, if the first condition is not met.  So:

Comment: Thanks -- but the reason why this won't really work is because the score1 between 30 and 80 don't have much of a priority; both ends of the score are good for their own reasons. The higher score2 is, the better. But there are barely any NULLs in score2, so that doesn't help much beyond ordering score2 by DESC. It's much more about adding the NULLs to score1 only if it's absolutely necessary (because the score1 NULLs are usable but worse than people with actual scores). Any ideas?

Comment: @Ryan. . . I missed a nuance in your question.  You specifically want the rows with `score1 is null`, when there are not enough rows for the full condition.

Comment: Sorry -- I might have done a poor job explaining it.  Your order by and limits are helpful -- though it's 25 _per organizer_, not in total. So I'd like there to be hundreds of results -- but at least 25 per organizer. So basically, based on the query, if the organizer's name repeats 25+ times, then use query 1 -- but if the organizer's name repeats less than 25 times, use query 2. Does that make sense?